# Using Regular Expressions with user input in PHP

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation, htmlspecialchars

I was wondering if anybody knew how to get around this problem.

I am gathering user input from a HTML form which is then posted using `htmlspecialchars` into PHP to avoid issues when using quotes/etc...

However, I also want to run server-side validation checks on the data being gathered through regular expressions - though I'm not sure how to go about this.

So far, I have thought of decoding the htmlspecialchars - but because I am going to be using the Strings straight away, this means that the code could break after I run this conversion. e.g: Let's say the user inputted a single quote, `"` into a field. This would be converted to `&quot;`, then if I decode this and use it in a variable, it could end up like: $string = `"`"`";` which is going to give me issues.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you manually pasting it? Or are you afraid that somehow a string with a single quote can not exist in php? How much do you understand/know about escaping characters?

Comment: @Sumurai8 I understand that I could escape the quotes, but the problem is that when I receive them, they'll be in the format of `&quot;`. Sure enough, I can decode this, but then here I have this problem:

`$inputString = "&quot;";`
`$inputStringDecoded = """;`
`$inputStringEscaped = addslashes($inputStringDecoded);`


However, the last line will not work, because we haven't yet ended the quotation marks of the String previously.

Comment: Why would you have issues with quotes in the first place? Don't use any of these decoding/encoding functions. What do you do with the user input? Write it to a database? In that case use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the difference between data and how this data is altered to be parseable in a certain context.

A php string can contain any data. What is stored in this string is the "raw" form: the form in which we want to manipulate the data if needed.

In certain contexts, not all characters are valid. For example, in a html textarea, the `<` and `>` characters may not be used, because they are special characters. We still want to be able to use these characters. To use special characters in a context, we *escape* these characters. By escaping a special character it looses its special meaning. In the context of a html textarea, the `<` character is escaped as the sequence `&lt;`. Unlike the `<` character, this escaped sequence does not have a special meaning in html, and thus if we send the following sequence to the browser, it knows how to parse that sequence and display the right thing: `<textarea>&lt;</textarea>`. When we talk about what the data is that this textarea contains, we do not say that it contains `&lt;`, but instead we say that it contains `<`.

As you said, in a php script, in a double quoted string, the `"` character has a special meaning. This has *only* to do with **parsing**. PHP simply does not know how to parse a sequence `$str = """;`. If we would want to have the double quote in such a double quoted string, we would need to escape it. We escape a double quote in a php double quoted string by prepending it with a `\`. To make a string containing a single double quote, using the double quoted notation, you would write `$str = "\"";`.

**However, none of this matters.**. You are taking input from a html form. When you click the submit button, the browser reads what is in the textarea(, and decodes it as html<sup>?</sup>). The browser then encodes it in a way as dictated by the form tag, and sends it to the server. The server then decodes the blob of text back in it's raw data form. That data is passed to PHP, and it is this form you will encounter in `$_POST['myTextarea']`.

In conclusion: If data is encoded, realize for which context it was encoded and decode it based on that context. You do not need to escape for php quoted strings, because you are working on internal strings. There is nothing to parse. Remind yourself that when you are going to use the data somewhere, that you should take care that all special characters in your data for that particular context are escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `htmlspecialchars()` function is called **after** posting the form to PHP. Simplest solution then will be to match against regular expression first and then do `htmlspecialchars()`.

Also, if you have string encoded with `htmlspecialchars()`, after decoding with `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, PHP internal representation will be `"\""`, so you break nothing. There is big difference how you write strings by hand to PHP file and how PHP internally handle them. You really don't need to be bothered by this.